# Plotly Indicator Graph how to hide/remove the indicator value

Tags: plotly, formatting, visualization

Hello folks,
I want to remove/hide the indicator value which is marked red colour in the below image. please suggest something to achieve this.

[image]

planned to achieve like following

[image]

thanks in advance

I tried via css to hide the value but it was like showing space by replacement which is not good.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provide a minimal reproducible example in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `go.Indicator`, you can pass the argument `mode='delta'` to hide the number:

```
fig = go.Figure(
    go.Indicator(
        mode='delta',
        value=105.42,
        delta={'reference':100, 'relative':True},
        title={'text':'increase in cost'}
    )
)
fig.show()
```

[image]